# Will increasing pool size for Mongo degrade performance?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, concurrency

We have 200 threads making HTTP requests and then storing data from those requests into a Mongo collection. We are seeing the following error because the pool size is too small:

```
"could not obtain connection within 5.0 seconds. The max pool size is currently 1; consider increasing the pool size or timeout."
```

Naturally, we increased the pool size to 200 so that each thread can maintain a connection to Mongo.

But we're not seeing much of a performance difference. Does increasing the pool size beyond a certain limit degrade Mongo performance? Specifically, is it advisable generally in Mongo to use 200 - 1000 connections?

The bottleneck may be elsewhere in the code, but we just want to confirm that increasing the pool size to 200 (or even 1000) will not adversely affect Mongo throughput (and should help if there are no other bottlenecks). We have read elsewhere that it may.